# Why is my Perl system command giving me a syntax error?

Tags: perl, unix, command

The Perl script that contains a Unix command to grep the ethernet NICs cannot be executed within the script! I have tried "qx" , $var and "system" but it does not seem to work!

The codes:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Term::ANSIColor;

print "\nYou are now in Showing Ethernet Cards!\n\n";

print "**************************\n";
print "|Ethernet Cards Available|\n";
print "**************************\n";

print "\nThe Ethernet Cards that are available are: "; 
my $ex = system ('ifconfig | awk '{print $1}' | egrep "eth|lo"');
print "$ex";
```

When executed the error "syntax error at ./ethercards.pl line 14, near "'ifconfig | awk '{"
Execution of ./ethercards.pl aborted due to compilation errors." shows up in the terminal.

Does anyone have any thoughts on this? Thanks!

Comment: Erm....Brian can you stop the editing thing? The name for the question does not sound right....

Comment: Can you stop spelling Perl incorrectly? Your question is about your syntax error, not executing a command. Your title is wrong. Your script never executes because it never compiles. Your problem has nothing to do with system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Syntax highlighting also suggests that your system string is broken. Try

```
system ('ifconfig | awk \'{print $1}\' | egrep "eth|lo"');
```

Comment: Strange...Why is there an extra "0" poping up? when I run the command purely on the terminal it does not have the zero but when its being run in the script a "0" pops up. Any thoughts on that? [EDIT] Just take away the "my $ex = ".....

Comment: The zero is the return value of your command. Zero usually means there was no error.

Comment: So is there a way to remove the zero?

Comment: Try the backtick operator instead. System itself prints to the stdout, and its return value is the exit code. Your print statement prints only the return value (the exit code). http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators

Answer (score 4):

You are using the `'` as the string delimiter but the `'` also shows up in the string.

You then mistake the return value of [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) as the output of the command. When a command doesn't do what you expect, read its docs.

You're also doing a bit too much work on the command line. You're already in Perl, so avoid creating extra processes when you don't need to:

```
my @interfaces = `/sbin/ifconfig` =~ m/^(\w+):/gm;

print "interfaces are @interfaces\n";
```

If you only want some interfaces, throw a `grep` in there:

```
my @interfaces = grep { /^(?:eth|lo)/ } `/sbin/ifconfig` =~ m/^(\w+):/gm;

print "interfaces are @interfaces\n";
```

I like to use the full path to executables so I know which one I'm getting. :)

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for your reply! I know this code works but sometimes the directory changes therefore I need to run the command instead. Thanks for your answer though! + Rep!

Comment: What does a directory have to do with this? This code is just the Perl version of your string of commands. There's no functional difference.

Comment: There is a restriction of root and non-root users.

Comment: What does that have to do with anything?

Answer (score 0):

If you need the output of your program, then write:

```
my $ex = qx!ifconfig | awk '{print \$1}' | egrep "eth|lo"!;
print "$ex";
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply! Works nicely! Sorry but first comes first serve....But up reps!